# NodeJS Express 4.9 and Socket.IO - 404 error on socket.io.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to create an Express app with Socket.IO. It seems like Express has changed quite a lot and most of the code online about getting the 2 to work together is out of date. This is what I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

The server starts ok and says

```
info - socket.io started
```

However the front-end has a 404 error on http://example.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js

*edit*

If I add

```
http.listen(8080);
```

The server runs twice on port 3000 and 8080, the 3000 version does not load socket.io.js and the 8080 version does. How can I have it so the server is only running on 3000? changing it to 3000 errors and it tries to listen twice

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to make the changes in bin/www.js instead of app.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('test1');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var server = http.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `io` include to:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

And towards the bottom add something like:

```
http.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', http.address().port);
});
```

Comment: I get the error message "object is not a function" if I change the require to that

Comment: What version of Socket.io are you using?

Comment: ~0.9.16. If you see my edit your suggestion about http.listen kinda works but it seems like express is also starting the server with it's own code on 3000 so it's running twice now

Comment: Gotcha, why not use ~1.x? They need to both use the same port. Sorry, the version was not specified and apparently it needs to be 1.x for this approach. Either upgrade or try `app.listen` instead of `http.listen`

Comment: 1.1 seems pretty much the same and app.listen errors.

Comment: I'm not able to confirm that is true -- https://github.com/kevireilly/ExpressSocket